# Unable to display a link to Public home page in easyadmin bundle (Symfony 2)

Tags: php, symfony, menu, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm currently using easyadmin like backoffice for an application that i developped, so basically everything works fine except the fact that i don't know how to display a link in admin panel so that when clicked it brings back the user to the application homepage.

This is my config.yml file

```
    imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: "@utiBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml" }

framework:

    translator: ~
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: utiUserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur

easy_admin:
    site_name: 'UTI-FMS - Retour'
    design:
        brand_color: 'rgb(176,33,26)'

    entities:
        Utilisateur:
            class: utiUserBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
            list: 
                fields: ['enabled', 'username', 'email', 'roles','lastLogin','role',{property : 'signature', type : 'image', base_path: '%app.path.user_signature%'} ]

            show:
                fields: [{property : 'signature', type : 'image', base_path: '%app.path.user_signature%'} ]                       

            form:
                fields: ['enabled', 'username', 'email', 'roles', 'lastLogin','role','plain_password', { property: 'imageFile', type: 'vich_image' }]

        Piece:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Piece
            list:
               fields: ['id','code','designation','quantite','prixUnitaire','magasin','meuble']
        Demande:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Demande
            list:
               fields: ['id','dateCreation','immatriculation','kilometrage','etat','casier']
        Reparation:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Reparation
            list:
               fields: ['id', 'nom','description','categorie']
            form:
               fields: ['nom', 'description','categorie']


        Categorie:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Categorie
            list:
               fields: ['id','nom','description']

            form:
                fields: ['nom','description']

        DemandeAchats:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\DemandeAchats
            list:
               fields: ['id','dateCreation', 'idDemandeTravaux','etat']     

        Vehicule:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Vehicule
            list:
               fields: ['id','immatriculation','chassis','type','marque','anneeCircu','etat','kilometrage']

            form:
               fields: ['immatriculation','chassis','type','marque','anneeCircu','etat','kilometrage']



        Mouvement:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Mouvement


        Fournisseur:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Fournisseur
            list:
               fields: ['id', 'nom', 'telephone1', 'telephone2','email1', 'email2']
            form:
               fields: ['nom', 'telephone1', 'telephone2','email1', 'email2']

        MouvementPiece:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\MouvementPiece
            list:
               fields: ['idDemandeTravaux', 'idDemandeAchats','nomPiece','nomFournisseur','dateMouvement','nature','quantite','prixUnitaire']
            form:
               fields: ['idDemandeAchats','nomPiece','nomFournisseur','dateMouvement','nature','quantite','prixUnitaire']

        Magasin:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Magasin
            list:
               fields: ['id','nom']
            form:
              fields: ['nom']
        Meuble:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Meuble
            list:
               fields: ['id','nom','magasin']
            form:
                fields: ['nom','magasin']
        Casier:
            class: uti\utiBundle\Entity\Casier
            list:
               fields: ['id','nom','meuble','magasin']
            form:
               fields: ['nom','meuble', 'magasin']



parameters:
    app.path.user_signature: /uploads/signatures

vich_uploader:
   db_driver: orm
    # ...
   mappings:
       user_signature:
         uri_prefix: %app.path.user_signature%
         upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/signatures


knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"" 
        options:    []
    image:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage.exe\""
        options:    []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip is to add every entity in the menu sub-section of design section:

```
easy_admin:
    site_name: 'UTI-FMS - Retour'
    design:
        brand_color: 'rgb(176,33,26)'
        menu:
            - { label  : 'Entités' }
            - { entity : 'Utilisateur', label: 'Utilisateur' }
            - { entity : 'Piece', label: 'Piece' }
            - { entity : 'Demande', label: 'Demande' }
            - { entity : 'Reparation', label: 'Reparation' }
            - { entity : 'Categorie', label: 'Categorie' }
            - { entity : 'DemandeAchats', label: 'Demandes Achats' }
            - { entity : 'Vehicule', label: 'Machine' }
            - { entity : 'Fournisseur', label: 'Fournisseur' }
            - { entity : 'MouvementPiece', label: 'Mouvement piece' }
            - { entity : 'Magasin', label: 'Magasin' }
            - { entity : 'Meuble', label: 'Meuble' }
            - { entity : 'Casier', label: 'Casier' }
            - { entity : 'Chauffeur', label: 'Chauffeur' }
            - { entity : 'Mouvement', label: 'Mouvement' }
            - { label : ''}
            - { label : 'Accueil', route: '_accueil' }
```